# Improve command definition to avoid possible break

Tags: macros, best-practices

The following defines my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{totcount}
\newcounter{totalpoints}
\regtotcounter{totalpoints}

\newcommand{\shcpoint}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{totalpoints}{#1}%
  \ifnum#1<2
    (\emph{#1 point})\hphantom{\em s}%
  \else
    (\emph{#1 points})%
  \fi\quad
}

\newcommand{\totalpoints}{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \leavevmode\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\llap{\textbullet}}\!\hrulefill\\[-0.825ex]%
    \null\hfill\bfseries Total Points: \total{totalpoints}~~\rlap{\rule{0.4pt}{3ex}}%
    }
}
\begin{document}
This questionary has a total of \total{totalpoints}~points.
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \shcpoint{1} Easy question
 \item \shcpoint{2} Some random question
 \item \shcpoint{3} Other question
\end{enumerate}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\totalpoints
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I am concerned about is if the command

```
\newcommand{\totalpoints}{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \leavevmode\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\llap{\textbullet}}\!\hrulefill\\[-0.825ex]%
    \null\hfill\bfseries Total Points: \total{totalpoints}~~\rlap{\rule{0.4pt}{3ex}}%
    }
}
```

will break maybe at the ends of pages and give half of the output in one and half in the other? That is, if defined as is, is `break` free so that the whole total points design stays intact even when at the end of a page? Note as it is, the command already yields the desired result.

If there are better ways of achieving the same output but in more robust manner, I would appreciate insights. I know for a fact that I can replicate the output in TikZ.

Comment: it's a parbox and boxes never break (you are missing one `%` at the end of the penultimate line though)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Other than that, is the command properly defined? Are there any other suggestions to make it better or other flavors to achieve the same result? Appreciate the input. :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle wanna make that an answer, or do you want to ping egreg for the EOL? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would you make an answer?

Answer (score 3):

It's a parbox and boxes never break however to avoid spurious white space you are missing one `%` at the end of the penultimate line.

```
\newcommand{\totalpoints}{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \leavevmode\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\llap{\textbullet}}\!\hrulefill\\[-0.825ex]%
    \null\hfill\bfseries Total Points: \total{totalpoints}~~\rlap{\rule{0.4pt}{3ex}}%
    }%
}
```

Comment: And `\leavevmode` is redundant as `\raisebox` does it. Moreover `\null\hfill` should be `\hspace*{\fill}`.